# What's the functionality of the function pm_runtime_put_sync()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

The function `pm_runtime_put_sync()` is called in [spi-omap2-mcspi.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L1441)

Can somebody please explain what actually this function call does.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It calls __pm_runtime_idle(dev, RPM_GET_PUT) internally which is documented as

> int __pm_runtime_idle(struct device *dev, int rpmflags)
>   Entry point for runtime idle operations.
>   * @dev: Device to send idle notification for.
>   * @rpmflags: Flag bits.
>   *
>   * If the RPM_GET_PUT flag is set, decrement the device's usage count and
>   * return immediately if it is larger than zero.  Then carry out an idle
>   * notification, either synchronous or asynchronous.
>   *
>   * This routine may be called in atomic context if the RPM_ASYNC flag is set,
>   * or if pm_runtime_irq_safe() has been called.

here are the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/pm_runtime.h#L219) and [Documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/power/runtime.c#L873)